# How to get the last character of string in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input

```
<items>
    <item id="1" name="aaa" old_level="5,4,3,2,1" new_level="5,4,3,2,1,0"/>
    <item id="2" name="bbb" old_level="3,2,1" new_level="3,2,1"/>
    <item id="3" name="ccc" old_level="4,3,2" new_level="4,3,2"/>
</items>
```

i need to check whether the last char of new_level is zero or not. How can i do this with xslt?

Answer (score 6):

If you have XSLT/XPath 2.0, you can use an XPath like this (or adapt for your specific need):

```
//item[ends-with(@new_level,'0')]
```

If you only have XSLT/XPath 1.0, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="length" select="string-length(@new_level)"/>
    <xsl:if test="substring(@new_level,$length) = '0'">
        <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Martin just out of interest is my first 2.0 answer less robust than your one (I upvoted yours :)

Comment: thank you your 1.0 suggestion is working, unfortunately i don't have 2.0

Comment: @smj, your solution is fine for the posted question. Mine might be a bit too complicated but any time I see a value looking like a list of items I am tempted to tokenize it to process individual items.

Comment: @martin thanks for that, I guess with tokenise you can do a lot more things, it just happens that this problem is one you can do without it.

Answer (score 2):

With XSLT 2.0 it is easy: `<xsl:template match="item[tokenize(@new_level, ',')[last()] eq '0']">..</xsl:template>`.